# how to restrict XLS2CSVmra to one sheet only?

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssf

i need to read XLS(not XLSX) file efficiently and I found the XLS2CSVmra example of POI, the problem is that I need to read one sheet only (i have sheet name sheet index etc.).
Is there any way to restrict reading to one sheet only?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be really simple - in the record handler for BOFRecord, when it has worked out the sheet, just have it stop processing when it sees the start of the sheet after the one you want. Done!

Comment: Thank you, but events will continue to call, plus how to start with second sheet for example skipping previous sheets?

Comment: Ignore all the records until you hit the required BOFRecord